# a sql query with multiple search word

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i use following query to get all data which contains the some words (which is split by a function) in the *name* column of the inventoryLocalization table.

in the example i have split "red green blue" string. 
as it should be, it returned all rows like **OR** operator.

```
SELECT distinct 
inL.name
FROM dbo.[inventoryLocalization] inL
JOIN fnSplitString (N'red green blue',' ' ) words ON (inL.name LIKE '%'+ words.item +'%')
```

My question is, is it possible to get rows which has all words, as in the **AND** operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select inL.name from dbo.[inventoryLocalization] inL 
where not exists
    (select 1 from fnSplitString(N'red green blue',' ') words 
    where (inL.name NOT LIKE '%'+ words.item +'%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @SomeWords NVARCHAR(200), @Num INT

SET @SomeWords = 'red green blue'

SELECT @Num = COUNT(*)
FROM fnSplitString (@SomeWords,' ')

SELECT inL.name
FROM dbo.[inventoryLocalization] inL
JOIN fnSplitString (@SomeWords,' ' )words 
ON (inL.name LIKE '%'+ words.item +'%')
GROUP BY inL.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = @Num
```