# Search Products from Word by Word

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the using the following SQL,

```
SELECT * FROM Products P
WHERE  (P.Name LIKE '%'+@Keyword+'%')
```

Now I need to search word by word, means when I enter `Retina Sony` then I need to search `Retina` in Name field `AND` `Sony` in Name field. Means I need to match all words in keyword to anme field. The above query is not working for me. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer,

```
SELECT  * from [Products] P
WHERE   NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Split(@Keyword,' ') Words WHERE (P.Name NOT LIKE '%' + Words.Items +'%'))
```

Got it from, [a sql query with multiple search word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048480/a-sql-query-with-multiple-search-word)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to split the string with space some thing like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
@String VARCHAR(200),
@Delimiter VARCHAR(5)
)

RETURNS @SplittedValues TABLE
(
OccurenceId SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1),
SplitValue VARCHAR(200)
)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @SplitLength INT

WHILE LEN(@String) > 0
BEGIN

SELECT @SplitLength = (CASE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) WHEN 0 THEN

LEN(@String) ELSE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) -1 END)

INSERT INTO @SplittedValues

SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,1,@SplitLength)

SELECT @String = (CASE (LEN(@String) - @SplitLength) WHEN 0 THEN ''

ELSE RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @SplitLength - 1) END)

END

RETURN
```

Then use this function like:

```
SELECT * FROM Products P
WHERE  (P.Name in (Select * from dbo.Split(@Keyword, ' ')) )
```

Comment: This is what I am talking about @user960567

Comment: I am planning to do this function myself but this should nail it.

Comment: @user960567 first test the function, it should give you words in different rows, rest just a simple query

Comment: @ChristianMark, Prevez Alam, this is not working, see sample `DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(500) = 'Sony Large Retina';
DECLARE @Keyword VARCHAR(500) = 'Sony Retina';

SELECT 1 WHERE  @Name IN (SELECT Items FROM Split(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Keyword)) ,' ') )`

Comment: @user960567 , did you test the split function, plz show the output of your split function,

Comment: Split is correct I am sure. The problem is that I need to match all words in keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the perfect use case for Full Text Search:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
(
    ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Products PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Name NVARCHAR(100)
)
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG mycatalog;
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Products
( 
    Name LANGUAGE 1033
) 
KEY INDEX PK_Products ON mycatalog; 
GO

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Products
WHERE   FREETEXT(Name, 'Retina AND Sony') -- will match any text that contains the two words, their inflectional forms or synonyms
```

There are a few ways to search, the above is just one example.

See: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use if event.
Convert inputed string to array and try it :

```
WHERE  
   (
      P.Name LIKE '%'+@Keyword[0]+'%' OR
      P.Name LIKE '%'+@Keyword[1]+'%'
      ....
   )
```

---

that is my idea.

Comment: Sony Interim was a example. The keyword may be compose of 1,2,3,4,etc words

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos) 
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
GO

DECLARE @DelimitedString NVARCHAR(128)
SET @DelimitedString = 'Duckman,Cornfed,Ajax,Charles,Mambo'
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@DelimitedString, ',')

DECLARE @Keyword nvarchar(128)
SET @Keyword = 'Retina,Cornfed'

select *  from Products p where p.name in 
(SELECT Data FROM dbo.Split(@Keyword, ','))
```

check now this

This i have tested it retruning me the the words

Comment: It's not woirking. Please understand match all words of keyword in Name Field

Comment: Thanks anyway I got the answer from another post.